# Converting an Object List to a String List

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, lambda

What's a better way to write the following? Can I do it with a Lambda expression?

```
List<string> managerList = new List<string>();
foreach (Manager m in matchedManager)
{
    managerList.Add(m.FullName);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes you can use [LINQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb308959.aspx). Like this:

```
List<string> managerList = matchedManager.Select(m => m.FullName).ToList();
```

Comment: I thought so, trying to figure out why I'm getting Object reference not set to an instance of an object errors on both.

Comment: @NathanMcKaskle Are you sure `matchedManager` is non-null?

Comment: Positive, I checked that.

Comment: you may have null items in `matchedManager` ... try `matchedmanager.Where(i=>i!=null).Select(m=>m.FullName)`